# Trying to get maxNumber out of an array, fails to reach the last element

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, jbutton, jtextfield

I am trying to get a GUI set up with a **FlowLayout** some **JLabels**, **JTextFields** and **JButtons**. Six **JTextFields**, five of them to get input by the user, input must a number, last JTextField shows the result depending on which button is clicked. JButtons: average, minimum, maximum. At the moment, when I try to get the maximum number it works up the fourth field. If there is a higher value at fifth field, it won’t show as the highest value.

I used a for loop that iterates though an array containing all numbers. Followed by an if condition that looks like this:

```
if(numbers[i]>maxValue)
```

where maxValue is set at zero.

```
public void getMax()
{
    double maxValue=0;
    double numbers[] = {num1,num2,num3,num4,num5};

    for(int i=0;i<=numbers.length-1;i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i]>maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = numbers[i];  
        }
    }
    textResult = String.valueOf(maxValue);
    resultField.setText(textResult);
}
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned below, my problem wasn't at the for loop and instead was at my parsingNumbers() fixed it and it works perfectly now. Thank you all.

Comment: What is your question? Does your code work?

Comment: It compiles and runs almost fine. The problem is I cannot get the highest value to show if it's in the fifth field. It will only show up to those in the first four fields.

Comment: Ok well you need to show us exactly how you are using the method, because there's nothing in the code you have shown us to explain that. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Getting accustomed to posting here. I’m trying to format the code so I can post it here, but it won’t allow me. Shows me a text that says “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code…”. I did copy and paste it from the IDE editor.

Comment: If you paste it in unformatted I can format it.

Comment: How can I post my code without infringing this site’s guidelines?

Comment: How can I do this? Should I send you a message? Says that it's too long to post it here.

Comment: Don't post it all. Just post just enough to reproduce the problem. If the method works for `num1`, `num2`, `num3` and `num4` there might just be something wrong with the way you are using `num5`.

Comment: The promlem was at my Parsenumber(), fixed and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and ist works as expected. maxValue will be set to 4.0. So the failure seems to be somewhere else in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Angelo Berlin is right.

But why not use Java itself? E.g.:

```
textResult = String.valueOf(DoubleStream.of(numbers).max().getAsDouble());
```

or if Java 8 is not available:

```
Collections.max(...)
```

Comment: I wasn’t aware of this. Removed the the for loop and instead left that line of code. My problem still persists, I cannot get the highest value at the last field. I’ll post the whole code, sorry if it’s a bit unorganized. I'll keep checking the rest of the code in the meanwhile.

Answer (score -3):

It's in your for loop.

```
 for(int i=0;i<=numbers.length-1;i++)
```

Currently, `numbers.length` is **5**. This is because you have **five values** in array `numbers`.

**But, you are only looping over 4 of those numbers!**

By doing `i<=numbers.length-1`, you are saying to loop for only **four** values. Instead, you should use `i<=numbers.length`

```
i=0

i=1

i=2

i=3

i=4
```

**WILL NOT INCREMENT I = 5**

Instead, you want to go through **ALL** of the values, because you are not **just** comparing the first four values, instead you are comparing the first **five** values.

All you need to do, is remove the `-1.` That way, `i` will increment through **all five numbers in your array:**

```
i=0

i=1

i=2

i=3

i=4

i=5
```

Let me know if this worked,

```
{Ruchir}
```

Comment: the condition in his loop is `i<=numbers.length-1`, not `i<numbers.length-1`. I actually see nothing wrong with his code and suspect something else.

Comment: try running it ;) `i<=numbers.length-1` and `i<numbers.length` are equivalent, at least when `i` is an `int`.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=numbers.length-1;i++)` will go through all 5 values if `numbers.length` is 5.

Comment: There are **5** values between 0 and 4 included, namely: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.